# Why am I not required to implement Animatable's Protocol required property

Tags: swiftui, shapes

So just curious about one thing. When creating a custom shape and conforming to Shape I am required to implement

```
func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path
```

Cool.

Now when I look up Path I see this:
[image]

And that it conforms to:

[image]

Now when I look up the first requirement: Animatable, I see that it has some required implementation:

[image]

Then why am I not required to add this data to every custom shape I create?

I have used animatableData before, but only optionally. If I understand the docs right then this isn't optional but required.

Any clarification is appreciated!

Edit: Edited title to better reflect subject matter

Comment: Because of the sentence after ***Required***. The protocol provides a default implementation in a protocol extension, and the `associatedtype` can be inferred.

Comment: The associatedType is defined inside `Path` already as `public typealias AnimatableData = EmptyAnimatableData`